# Как поменять аватарку?

Tags: поддержка, аватар-пользователя

У меня ничего не получается. Захожу на страницу профиля, кликаю по аве - и меня перекидывает на страницу активности.

Comment: Нужно заходить на вкладку "Править"

Comment: В дубликате указано как зайти на вкладку. Там же можно сменить и аватар, и ник, а также описание о себе.